# "Java Web Start not found" using java 1.6

Tags: java, macos

I'm running Mac OS 10.7, and I have the latest version of java installed. Nonetheless, when I try to launch the TopCoder competition arena, I see this error:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: 1) Did you have a question? 2) What do you see [here](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.specification.version%2Cjava.version&format=TSV)?

Comment: I'd like to know why my computer can't seem to find the Java Web Start, even though it should come installed with the latest version of java. This error demonstrates that something is preventing my computer from accessing Java Web Start, and I'd like to find out what.

Comment: I see: Name Value
java.specification.version 1.6
java.version 1.6.0_29

Comment: It seems *either* that web page, or your local set-up, is broken.

Comment: The site is widely used and unlikely to be broken. Do you have any suggestions for how I can go about probing my local setup to find out what's wrong?

Comment: *"The site is widely used and unlikely to be broken"*  Is the applet broken?  If not, a lot of people would simply opt for that & not bother to think of the JWS option again (let alone report a problem). *"have any suggestions"*  Sorry, no.  JRE set-up is not one of my areas of expertise, & I am not familiar with OS X.

Comment: You could try the following : 
Download http://www.topcoder.com/contest/classes/ContestApplet.jar and then run
java -classpath ContestApplet.jar com.topcoder.client.contestApplet.runner.generic www.topcoder.com 5001 'http://tunnel1.topcoder.com/tunnel?dummy' TopCoder .The original post is at http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/;jsessionid=06C5AC175CDD8065B7CD87A36B0FCBDB?module=Thread&threadID=621739&start=0&mc=16#1186034

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clicking on the button? Viewing the page content, I see that this button just downloads a JNLP file, which just works for me.

The site is trying to detect if something handles 'application/x-java-jnlp-file', but no plugin is registered to handle it. If you have Java installed it should register a MIME type handler for JNLP files, so it sounds like a bug. File one with Oracle.